# Перемножение факториалов

Tags: c#

Сейчас задачка попалась, не могу сообразить, как ее решить:

Вычислить 1!*2!*3!.....*n!

без использования рекурсии, вложенных циклов и функции степени

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int res = 1;
for (int i = 1, k = 1; i <= n; i++, k = k * i)
  res = res * k;
```

*(проблема переполнения не рассматривается)*

---

```js
function factorialProduct(n) {
  var res = 1;
  for (var i = 1, k = 1; i <= n; i++, k = k * i)
    res = res * k;
  return res;
}
console.log(factorialProduct(3));
console.log(factorialProduct(4));
console.log(factorialProduct(5));
console.log(factorialProduct(6));
console.log(factorialProduct(10));
```

Comment: нельзя использовать степень

Comment: Спасибо, не думал, что можно факториал в условие цикла засунуть